# Custom Exporting of rows from ag-grid having pagination, into CSV (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have a grid to which there are 2 features in my application regarding export.

1. Exporting "only the rows which are visible to the user". For example, there might be 50 rows on the DOM but only 20 rows might be visible to the user(remaining can be seen by scrolling). In this scenario, when clicking on this option, only 20 records should be exported.
2. Exporting n number of rows, by first fetching them from API and then "applying formatters" on them

Please note that I have formatters and transformers which should be applied on the rows before we export them.

---

The closest solution which I came up with, is to take the rows(either current displaying (or) after fetching from api) and creating a new grid below(with 'display:none' so that user won't see it). Now use `api.exportDataAsCsv(params)` on the new grid. But this does not seems to be a good approach.

Another point to be noted is that in the second feature, after fetching n number of rows, I don't want to add the fetched rows to my currently displaying grid(Or should I to achieve the functionality?). All I want is to fetch rows, apply formatters and export them into CSV/XLS.

Any suggestions/insights would be helpful.